# Clang-format misformatting enum braces and ignoring settings

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am learning how to use **clang-format** with my C++ projects, but have stumbled on an issue.
My code currently formats to the following:

```cpp
enum class foo
{
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
};

enum bar
{
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
};
```

However, I would like it to format to this:

```cpp
enum class foo {
    enum1, 
    enum2, 
    enum3
};

enum bar {
    enum1,
    enum2,
    enum3
};
```

Said more technically, I would like the braces not to wrap for enums.
My current settings include this:

```yaml
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum:       false
```

I thought this would disable brace wrapping for enums, however there seems to be some other setting overpowering it. What do I need to change/what other information should I give to pinpoint the issue? Thanks
BTW it is clang-format v. `12.0.0`
here is my .clang-format content:
https://pastebin.com/ce9PGjuw

```yaml
---
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveMacros: None
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: None
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: None
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: None
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
AttributeMacros:
  - __capability
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: Never
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     100
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat:   false
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
StatementAttributeLikeMacros:
  - Q_EMIT
IncludeBlocks:   Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<ext/.*\.h>'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
    CaseSensitive:   false
IncludeIsMainRegex: '([-_](test|unittest))?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentRequires:  false
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 0
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
Standard:        Auto
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        4
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Always
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
  - NS_SWIFT_NAME
  - CF_SWIFT_NAME
...
```

Comment: What about other code like classes, functions, blocks? If you ever switch for one of these, you should do so for all the others, too, so either *consistently* K&R or *consistently* Allman, but not intermixing both!

Comment: People are going to magically know what setting could be overriding? Please post your entire `.clang-format` file.

Comment: @sweenish I have now put my entire file into the message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure clang-fromat to avoid wrap the brace for enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297520/how-to-configure-clang-fromat-to-avoid-wrap-the-brace-for-enum)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! So, it's a bug...