# How to configure clang-fromat to avoid wrap the brace for enum

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have an enum like this:

```
enum class Fruit {
  Apple = 0,
  Banana = 1
};
```

And the .clang-format configurations for the enum looks like this:

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: false
```

After applying clang-format, the brace is wrapped and the code become

```
enum class Fruit 
{
  Apple = 0,
  Banana = 1
};
```

How to config clang-format to keep the enum's original format?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a bug. It's currently been fixed here but they haven't released it yet:

- https://reviews.llvm.org/D99840
- https://reviews.llvm.org/D106349

Answer (score 0):

i think there is problem with your file you can't use `BraceWrapping` if `BreakBeforeBraces`  is not `Custom`